# How to get logged in userId from Blazor Server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using the standard Blazor Server with individual accounts scaffolded by Microsoft, how do I access the logged in userId inside of a component? .NET 5.

I've tried tapping into `AuthenticationStateProvider` and using this to get it, but that returns null.

```
 var authState = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

        if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var id = authState.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "nameidentifier")?.Value;
        }
```

Comment: Use `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` constant, not a magic string.

Comment: You can also use `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user information is stored in the `ClaimsPrincipal`. Here's a couple of extension methods I use:

```cs
public static long GetUserId( this ClaimsPrincipal principal )
{
    string val = principal.FindFirstValue( ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier );
    return long.Parse( val );
}

public static bool TryGetUserId( this ClaimsPrincipal principal, out long userId )
{
    if( principal.HasClaim( x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier ) )
    {
        userId = principal.GetUserId();
        return true;
    }

    userId = -1;
    return false;
}
```

And usage would something along the lines of:

```cs
// from a controller
long id = User.GetUserId();

// from an HTTPContext, i.e., middleware
bool hasId = context.User.TryGetUserId( out long userId );
```